# Why is my output values not printing-out correctly using C#?

Tags: arcgis

I am trying to output my results (2 lists results) into a text file, but I keep getting this error message printed on the text file, instead of the values "System.Collections.Generic.List`1 System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1 System String". I am getting the data error at this line:

```
strOutputs.Add(string.Join(",",List1, List2));
```

Any ideas why and how to resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: What "data error" is that exactly? And this looks like C# / .Net - is it? You are missing a language tag.

Comment: Yes, I am using C# with the ArcGIS Pro SDK 2.8. Here is the error that appears: "System.Collections.Generic.List1 System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List1 System String." Thanks for your help!